# React Redux error: default parameters should be last default-param-last

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

Using Redux in React I'm having a warning that the default parameters should be last default-param-last. on the line where I created the const warehouse. is there wrong on how I created the code? or is there a better code for that?

Here's my codes

```
import {SAVE_ACTION} from '../actions/save-action';


cons initialState = {
    datasToSave:[]
};

const warehouse = (state = initialState, {type, payload}) => {
    switch(type) {
        case SAVE_ACTION: {
            const {datasToSave} = payload
            return {
                ...state,
                dataToSave
                };
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default warehouse;
```

Comment: can you add the part with the dispath (action)

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a default for your action parameter:

```
import {SAVE_ACTION} from '../actions/save-action';


cons initialState = {
    datasToSave:[]
};

const warehouse = (state = initialState, {type, payload} = {}) => {
    switch(type) {
        case SAVE_ACTION: {
            const {datasToSave} = payload
            return {
                ...state,
                dataToSave
                };
            }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default warehouse;
```

There's nothing wrong with your code as such. The `default-param-last` eslint rule just means that in this case you need to specify a default on both params or disable the rule for that particular line. The rule wants you to do `({type, payload}, state = initialState) =>` but that won't work as redux will call your reducer with the parameters in a different order. I would set the default on the action parameter to fix this :).

Comment: It might be worth noting that default parameters don't have to be last in JavaScript (unlike some other languages, C# say). Any parameter which is passed in as `undefined` gets replaced with the default if there is one - so it's perfectly possible to call this reducer in such a way that the default for the first parameter gets used, even though the second parameter always has a defined value (it better be, as it's the default state for this part of the Redux store!).

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with above answer but you can also disable checking for default parameter last in .eslint file.

in .eslint file add/edit:

```
"default-param-last": 0
```

Comment: This unfortunately makes more sense as you might not want to comment dozens of reducers.